# update multiple image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I donot understand why it update only 1 image and loop it

Following is the html form code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url('admin/edit_property/' . $property['property_id']); ?>" class="form-horizontal" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Select Images</label>
        <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-top:1%;">
            <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple="multiple" > 

            <?php 
            foreach ($property_image as $property_images) { 
                ?> 
                <img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'uploads/' . $property_images['image_name']; ?>" width="42" height="42">
                <?php 
            } 
            ?>
        </div>
```

In my Controller I am looping through the files

```
foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $tmp_name) {

    $temps = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $new_file_name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

    move_uploaded_file($temps, "uploads/" . $new_file_name);                                           
    $this->crud_model->updated_property_image_records($new_file_name, $id); 

 }
```

This is the query in the Model

```
function updated_property_image_records($new_file_name, $id) {
    $update = $this->db->query("UPDATE property_image SET image_name='$new_file_name' where property_id= '$id' ");
}
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing the FORM... edit: are there dashes missing in "$this>crud_model>updated_property_..."?

Comment: sir kindly see it again

Comment: Ok. Please see my edit and please do a var_dump() of $_FILES after the upload (the structure might not be what you think)

Comment: can you please elaborate it

Comment: `$this>crud_model>updated_property_image_records($new_file_name, $id); `
Check this line

Comment: Instead of the foreach loop in the controller, please do a var_dump of $_FILES as asked by @LarsStegelitz **`var_dump($_FILES);` and update the question.**

Comment: and show full controller.

Comment: when i use var_dump($new_file_name); it show only show the name of 2nd file i want both file

Comment: we are here to help, but you have to help yourself first: two people have asked the same question yet you haven't provided the response "var_dump($_FILES); and update the question."

Comment: array(1) { ["files"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "3.png" [1]=> string(18) "Screenshot (2).png" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "image/png" [1]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpBC77.tmp" [1]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpBC78.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(396733) [1]=> int(107904) } } }